# String Split with comma

Tags: c#

I have a code for getting a string,the string contain the color names.I want to split the string separated by comma.here is my code.

```
public static string getcolours()
{
    string str = null;
    DBClass db = new DBClass();
    DataTable allcolours = new DataTable();
    allcolours = db.GetTableSP("kt_getcolors");
    for (int i = 0; i < allcolours.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string s = allcolours.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        string missingpath = "images/color/" + s + ".jpg";
        if (FileExists(missingpath))
        {

        }
        else
        {
             str = str + missingpath;


        }

    }
    return str;

}
```

Comment: Try looking up "C# string split".  - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Comment: Just google your title...

Comment: You tried something at least, there's a lot of exemple of this kind of situation online.

Comment: surely this must be a duplicate.

Comment: For future reference...if you find yourself writing code to do something that everyone needs to do at one point or another (like, say, splitting a string or joining a bunch of strings together), chances are there's a function or class in the BCL that already  does it.  A little searching can save you writing a bunch of code you don't have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
string[] yourStrings = s.Split(',');
```

**Actually, what I think you're asking for is a return string like this:**

```
"red, blue, green, yellow"
```

To achieve that, you need to use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/57a79xd0.aspx). Try this:

```
public static string getcolours()
{
    List<string> colours = new List<string>();
    DBClass db = new DBClass();
    DataTable allcolours = new DataTable();
    allcolours = db.GetTableSP("kt_getcolors");
    for (int i = 0; i < allcolours.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string s = allcolours.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        string missingpath = "images/color/" + s + ".jpg";
        if (!FileExists(missingpath))
        {
            colours.Add(missingpath);
        }
    }

    return string.Join(", ", colours);
}
```

Comment: but it doesn't return yourstring value..

Comment: @user2264616 Do you want to return the list of strings?

Comment: @Jodrell Just a variable name, it can be changed to whatever.

Comment: apologies, ignore jabber.

Comment: @mattytommo ..  Wow Great man.It is working as my need..Thanks a lot Sir.Super.

Comment: @user2264616 No problems! Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] words = s.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have empty values, use StringSplitOptions.

```
var colours = str.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: But I can't Return colours insted of return str.